# From where does the public variable names comes in inspector for TextMesh Pro?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am little confused from where does below names comes:

[image]

My script have below names without space. Does inspector adds space?

```
public TextMeshProUGUI countText;
public GameObject winTextObject;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, Unity creates the Inspector label by introducing a space wherever a capital letter occurs in the variable name.
It also removes leading underscore like `_myVariable` and also removes `m_myVariable`.

So to sum up:

`myVeryImportantVariable`  will be   `My Very Important Variable` 
`_myVeryImportantVariable`  will be   `My Very Important Variable` 
`m_myVeryImportantVariable`  will be   `My Very Important Variable`

Ofcourse whenever you need custom naming, like you want your variable name from code `public bool isDead;` to show up in the inspector like `Dead` do not hesitate to write a custom editor script.